# What does it mean if my voltage regulator is acting as a wire?

Tags: voltage-regulator, circuit-design, short-circuit

When i connect 24V to my input pin, and connect ground pin to my Ground, it gives a short circuit at the bench power supply. What does this mean? Did i kill my voltage regulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's probably burned out.

If you don't have the proper capacitors attached to the input and output, it's possible weird things will happen, but 90% chance it's just fried.

Make sure to take a look through the datasheet, and ensure that you're not exceeding any of the absolute maximum ratings. Also if there's an application circuit that shows the caps, try to copy those.

Comment: And make sure you didn't hook it up backwards, which can be distressingly easy with 3-terminal packages, and also with voltage regulators if you think that yours has the same pinout as the last one you used.

Comment: @TimWescott Thanks alot! Backwards as in, ground is connected to power and power is connected to ground?

Comment: Yes.  Or ground to power out and power-something connected to ground.  I've been designing circuits for 30 years and it's still the first thing I'd check on a prototype circuit (and something I get wrong embarrassingly often).

Comment: Yeah the pin-outs don't follow any kind of standard for some reason.